# Does the forgetful functor from the category of models of a cartesian theory preserve and create limits?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, categorical-logic, forgetful-functors

It is well-known that a monadic functor preserves and creates limits, which in particular shows that any algebraic category, or equivalently, any category of models of an algebraic theory, has limits, and the forgetful functor creates them.

I'm wondering whether the same holds for cartesian theories as well. Since cartesian theories corresponds exactly to some sort of partial algebras, I'm expecting this to hold. Also, as an example, in the case of the cartesian theory of categories this indeed holds. The theory of categories $\mathbb T$ is itself cartesian; and for any finitely complete category $\mathcal C$, $\mathbb T$ models in $\mathcal C$ are just internal categories in $\mathcal C$, and we denoted this category as $\mathbf{cat}(\mathcal C) = \mathrm{Mod}_\mathbb T(\mathcal C)$. Now it is well-known that the forgetful functor
$$ \mathbf{cat}(\mathcal C) \to \mathcal C^2 $$
preserves and creates limits (the codomain of the forgetful functor is $\mathcal C^2$ because the cartesian theory of categories has 2 sorts, viz. objects and morphisms).

I couldn't find any reference on this. It would be really helpful if you know any reference that contains such (either positive or negative) results; I guess this should be well-established.

Comment: What is "the" forgetful functor? Unlike for monads or algebraic theories, there is no canonical forgetful functor. (An extreme example: for every commutative ring $A$, there is a cartesian theory whose models are $A$-modules... but it is equally the cartesian theory whose models are left $\mathrm{M}_n (A)$-modules! So we have infinitely many forgetful functors to $\textbf{Set}$, all of which are monadic!)

Comment: @ZhenLin In my mind, the canonical forgetful functor for $\mathrm{Mod}_{\mathbb T}(\mathcal C)$ for of a cartesian theory $\mathbb T$ is always the functor $\mathrm{Mod}_{\mathbb T}(\mathcal C) \to \mathcal C^\Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is the set of sorts of the theory $\mathbb T$, sending each $\mathbb T$-model to its "underlying objects" corresponding to each sort.

Comment: @ZhenLin Now in the case you mentioned, for each ring $M_n(A)$ there is a corresponding cartesian (actually, algebraic) theory $\mathbb T_n$ whose models are $M_n(A)$-modules. Now $\mathrm{Mod}_{\mathbb T_n}(\mathcal C)$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{Mod}_{\mathbb T_m}(\mathcal C)$ for any $n,m > 0$ is due to the fact that these theories, equivalently, these rings, are Morita equivalent; but indeed, if they are viewed as different category (not up to equivalence) they will have different forgetful functors.

Comment: OK. It sounds like you are using the Elephant definition. I don't see a proof in the Elephant of the fact you are looking for, but I think no one doubts that it is true. (There are some subtleties anyway – if you are going to use this fact to prove that the category of models has limits, then you will need a direct proof; but if you already known that the category of models has limits then it is enough to show that the functor you ask about preserves limits and is conservative.)

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, thanks. I also looked up Elephant and didn't find anything. I tried to prove this using classifying topos. We know that cartesian theories has classifying topos of presheaf type, i.e. there exists some category $\mathcal C$ (should be finitely complete) that $[\mathcal C^{op},\mathbf{Set}]$ is the classifying topos of the cartesian theory $\mathbb T$, such that for any topos $\mathcal E$ we have $\mathrm{Mod}_\mathbb T(\mathcal E) \cong \mathbf{Geom}(\mathcal E,[\mathcal C^{op},\mathbf{Set}])$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Now by Diaconescu's theorem, $\mathbf{Geom}(\mathcal E,[\mathcal C^{op},\mathbf{Set}])$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{Flat}(\mathcal C,\mathcal E)$, the category of flat functors from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal E$. In the case of $\mathbb T$ only containing one sort, $\mathcal C$ should have a generating object $X$, and the forgetful functor translates to the evaluation functor $ev_X : \mathbf{Flat}(\mathcal C,\mathcal E) \to \mathcal E$. Then I'm stuck. I'm not sure when such evaluation functors create limits.

Comment: There is no need to use such complicated gadgets. If you use the hands-on definition of "model" in terms of signatures then you can prove it more or less directly: first show that the forgetful functor from the category of structures creates limits (tedious) then show that the inclusion of the category of models into the category of structures creates limits (easy).

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right. I'm just thinking that how to generalise such results in terms of the fragment of logic; because for more complicated fragment this obviously does not hold. E.g., the theory of fields only has a coherent axiomatisation, and the forgetful functor of fields into Set obviously does not create limits. I'm just not sure whether we have a clear cut on how complex our fragment of logic could be while we still have this result. If an argument could go for theories with presheaf classifying topos then at least we can say something much more general.

Comment: There is a theory of presheaf type whose models are fields, so there is no hope of generalising the result.